# Как кто делает поиск на сайте?

Tags: поиск, search

Народ, кто как делает поиск на сайте, через гугл, через сфинкс, через `%like%`?

Comment: Поиск чего именно необходим и среди каких данных?

Answer (score 1):

Чисто через %like% - это, конечно, извращение. Нормальный поиск по сложнее должен быть, для удобства пользователей. Так-то можно: гугл, яндекс, сфинкс. Также есть и хорошие плагины платные\бесплатные под разные популярные CMS. В принципе, самое простое через поисковых гигантов, но лучше заморочиться и настроить внутренний поиск без их участия.

Собственно, каков вопрос, таков и ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Выписываю на бумажке сущности, по которым будем искать, требования к поиску (фасетность, семантика, параметры и т.д.), платформы, на которых будет работать, необходимость масштабирования, уровень нагрузки, желательные рюшечки и прочее. Потом принимаю решение -- чем искать и как (при необходимости) преобразовать данные. Ну а дальше -- клавиатура и много мата...

Если серьёзно, то принципиальных вариантов 3:
 1. Средства БД.
 2. Встроенные поисковики.
 3. Поисковые движки (Солр, Сфинкс).

Answer (score 0):

Ждать индексации своего сайта в ПС не лучший вариант, они не всегда все в выдачу поставят. Я делал полнотекстовый поиск по 8000 текстовым работам с использованием LIKE. Ничего страшного, если запрос не состоит из пары символов. Я ставил ограничение, чтобы запрос был больше 10 символов, чтобы он имел смысл (более точный запрос, а не состоящий из одного слова) и базу не так грузил.

Comment: Как сделать fulltext поиск по двум таблицам.